# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character(s) in message header field: Authorization: Basic

Tags: java, html, soap, illegal-characters

I am writing a java class to trigger a webservice, but I am getting the error when trying to execute it.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character(s) in message header field: Authorization: Basic
```

when I remove the colon character from "Authorization: Basic ", I am not getting the error.

```
MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", serverURI  + "send");
headers.addHeader("Authorization: Basic ", "123456789123456789");
```

Is there a way to send the colon without any errors?

```
java -version
java version "1.7.0_131"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.6.9.0.el6_8-x86_64 u131-b00)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.131-b00, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Try escaping the colon with a preceding backslash. `headers.addHeader("Authorization\: Basic ", "123456789123456789");`

Comment: thanks @RobMoll ... tried it but it does not compile "smsWebService.java:74: illegal escape character"
smsWebService.java:74: illegal escape character
        headers.addHeader("Authorization\: Basic", "123456789123456789");

Comment: How about unicode? Try `\u003A` in place of the colon.

Comment: @RobMoll ... tried it ... compile ok, but same error:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character(s) in message header field: Authorization: Basic

Comment: Okay. My last attempt: Remove the blank space at the end of the string after "Basic": `headers.addHeader("Authorization: Basic", "123456789123456789");`

Comment: tried it ... same result :(
The same class file in another server is working fine if this gives an indication about the solution

Comment: I just edited my previous comment. I took out the escape character from in front of the colon. Please try removing the blank space and removing the escape character. Sorry.

Comment: same error :( once I remove the : it executes but I get an error from the remote server. btw thanks for helping out :)

Comment: Solved by replacing:

        headers.addHeader("Authorization: Basic ", "123456789123456789");

with

        headers.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic 123456789123456789");

Answer (score 2):

Solved by replacing:

```
headers.addHeader("Authorization: Basic ", "123456789123456789");
```

with

```
headers.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic 123456789123456789");
```

Answer (score 0):

I had copied the headers from a cURL call, which had "Authorization: ". Removing the colon solved the problem.